# How would you capture a discount that covers the cost of taxes with GA4 Purchase parameters?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Would I add a data layer variable for the purchase event outside of the items array? This is Google's recommendation for purchase events. I want to add a coupon code with a discount that covers the entire cost including taxes. This is what google has in their doc:

```
dataLayer.push({      
event: "purchase",
      ecommerce: {
          transaction_id: "T_12345",
          affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
          value: 25.42,
          tax: 4.90,
          shipping: 0,
          currency: "USD",
          coupon: "SUMMER_SALE",
          items: [
           {
            item_id: "SKU_12345",
            item_name: "Stan and Friends Tee",
            affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
            coupon: "SUMMER_FUN",
            currency: "USD",
            discount: 2.22,
            index: 0,
            item_brand: "Google",
            item_category: "Apparel",
            item_category2: "Adult",
            item_category3: "Shirts",
            item_category4: "Crew",
            item_category5: "Short sleeve",
            item_list_id: "related_products",
            item_list_name: "Related Products",
            item_variant: "green",
            location_id: "L_12345",
            price: 9.99,
            quantity: 1
          }]
      }
    });
```

I want to create a cart that gives the user for free. Or rather a $0 cart value. Would I add the coupon discount ($4.90 = value + tax) for the whole cart like this:

```
dataLayer.push({      
event: "purchase",
      ecommerce: {
          transaction_id: "T_12345",
          affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
          value: 0,
          tax: 4.90,
          shipping: 0,
          currency: "USD",
          coupon: "SUMMER_SALE",
          discount: 4.90,
          items: [
           {
            item_id: "SKU_12345",
            item_name: "Stan and Friends Tee",
            affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
            coupon: "SUMMER_FUN",
            currency: "USD",
            discount: 9.99,
            index: 0,
            item_brand: "Google",
            item_category: "Apparel",
            item_category2: "Adult",
            item_category3: "Shirts",
            item_category4: "Crew",
            item_category5: "Short sleeve",
            item_list_id: "related_products",
            item_list_name: "Related Products",
            item_variant: "green",
            location_id: "L_12345",
            price: 9.99,
            quantity: 1
          }]
      }
    });
```

Or would the discount amount including tax ($14.69 = intended discount for product + cost of tax) also be included in the discount for the item in the items array.

```
dataLayer.push({      
event: "purchase",
      ecommerce: {
          transaction_id: "T_12345",
          affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
          value: 0,
          tax: 4.90,
          shipping: 0,
          currency: "USD",
          coupon: "SUMMER_SALE",
          discount: 4.90,
          items: [
           {
            item_id: "SKU_12345",
            item_name: "Stan and Friends Tee",
            affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
            coupon: "SUMMER_FUN",
            currency: "USD",
            discount: 14.69,
            index: 0,
            item_brand: "Google",
            item_category: "Apparel",
            item_category2: "Adult",
            item_category3: "Shirts",
            item_category4: "Crew",
            item_category5: "Short sleeve",
            item_list_id: "related_products",
            item_list_name: "Related Products",
            item_variant: "green",
            location_id: "L_12345",
            price: 9.99,
            quantity: 1
          }]
      }
    });
```

This is [the doc from google that I've been referencing.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm#purchase)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Discount is an item level parameter; you may send a value for 'discount' with an item in the item array, but it is not a parameter of ecommerce so it is not available in that object.

It is users choice as to how to send and interpret numbers, but if you calculate tax on the net price which, in your example, is 0, then your tax should be 0--no need to discount tax. Of course, follow your own locales tax laws.

for more: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtm